LM339 Comparator Battery Discharge Cutoff Circuit
I have built a circuit where the battery supply voltage is a set of Li-ion batteries and I want to shut them down when the are discharged (there are 4 in series at between 14.4V and 16.8V).  Using a comparator I intend to operate a MOSFET (this part of the circuit it not done yet, nor in the question).  Using the battery power I divide it for input to the non-invetering LM339N input and I limit it to a 10V Zener diode for input to the inverting LM339N input.  I use a 3.9K pull up resistor at the output.  The measured output inversion point is at about 14.2V so far (should be 14.4V).  I have measurements:



Battery Voltage (pin 8)
Comparator (+)     (pin 5)
Comparator (-) (pin 6)
Comparator Output (pin 7)




12.650V
9.140V
9.954V
9.980V


14.270V
10.048V
10.047V
10.861V


14.503V
10.120V
10.071V
10.906V


14.725V
10.184V
10.087V
10.936V


15.144V
10.420V
10.120V
10.992V


15.530V
10.656V
10.138V
11.024V


16.823V
11.487V
10.197V
11.117V


17.241V
11.759V
10.207V
11.135V



The operating input voltage is safely Vcc-2V and the maximum Vcc is 36V

I ask why is the voltage at 12.650V not practically 0V?  I wonder why the output voltage at 17.241V is not greater than 15V?

Don't bother: a low voltage cutoff based on the total battery voltage is useless because it doesn't protect the Li-ion battery. By the time it shuts off, one of the cells is likely to be over-discharged, or even (gulp!) reversed.
In any case, your approach places a constant load on the battery that will over-discharge the cells even after the comparator shuts off the switch. (And I love how you placed a MOSFET across the battery. I can only imagine the smoke when you turn that MOSFET on.)
Instead, what you need is a Li-ion battery with a built-in protector BMS (Battery Management System). It will disable discharge when any one cell voltage is too low, regardless of the total battery voltage.

Please get a pre-designed BMS for your pack. These protect against over and under voltage, plus thermal protection and balancing the cells.
More here: https://www.batteryskills.com/what-is-3s-and-4s-battery-management-system/

I changed the voltage divider resistors that were in the hundreds of ohms to the hundreds of thousands of ohms and it is now working.
I searched for an answer to the question of how much current should the inputs to a comparator get and why, but I found almost nothing.  What I did find was some recommendations in some application notes that usually stated to make them about 5mA or less, but they never gave a reason, a clear explanation or a calculation.
NOTE:  The rest of the circuit was quickly drawn, I intend to use the drain of the MOSFET as the ground to the load and it will be the only path to ground for the load - but I have yet to try it.
Thanks for your responses.

The upper limit (and typical value) of comparator input current in normal operation is stated in the datasheet. Typically 25nA, maximum 400nA flows out of the comparator input pins for a TI LM393. If the impedance as seen at the output of a voltage divider is (say) 100kΩ then 400nA will change the voltage at the input by  40mV.  If you're planning on forcing the parasitic input diode to conduct, absolute maximum is stated as 50mA so you'd want to stay well away from that, and a few mA would be okay, but that's not normal operation at all.

But the power supply current of the LM393 is 0.5mA even without any other circuitry so it's unsuitable for Li-ion battery discharge protection since it will discharge the battery itself to a harmful degree unless you add additional circuitry to turn the protection circuitry off, which is pretty complex.

I did read about the 50mA, but I really do not see a calculation to minimize the current into the bases of the input transistors.  I think I(CE) = Beta x I(base) for the minimum.  For the batteries, I have parallel 3Ah (2x3Ah=6Ah) 18650 batteries that must work overnight in the cold with solar charging during the day; its the heater to keep the batteries warm that uses the power and I cannot afford to charge below 0C since that will ruin the batteries, nor should I store them below -20C, so it is necessary to save the batteries with a heater.

"input bias current" is the parameter

You ma have solver the proximate problem, but you're still stuck with the ultimate problem unsolved: your battery is not protected.
